# Download here map for a country directly (without selecting it)

Tags: android, here-api

I have to download here map for my `country` without using the complex `UI` for selecting it.

Simply I need to detect the `country` somehow and download the offline map for the `country` from here.

I know this will fix the problem.

```java
 List<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<>();
        idList.add(country.getId());
mMapLoader.installMapPackages(idList)
```

But I don't know how to get the `MapPackage` *country* object .

I don't want to implement a list `UI` and select *country* from it.

I want to detect my `MapPackage` *country* and download it directly.

Comment: Hi, the country code here map has is not similar to the ISO code / usual country code. I need a method to find my here-country.

Comment: any formate of country code?

Comment: my country object is of type `MapPackage`

Comment: https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/mapping/MobileMapPackage.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the locale of the device to find the country:

```
 String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayCountry();
```

or you can use the location through the sim used in the phone by the user:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryCode = tm.getSimCountryIso();
```

Comment: I'm not asking for getting the default county code. I need to know, how to get here-country-id from our country details?

Answer (score 0):

**below is the code for country code**

```
    String UserIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserIP))
{
    UserIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
string url = "http://freegeoip.net/json/" + UserIP.ToString();
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string jsonstring = client.DownloadString(url);
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserCountryCode"] = dynObj.country_code;
```

> Using the above function you can get Country code so that you can directly pass it as a parameter to your function
>   ex: mMapLoader.installMapPackages(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserCountryCode"])

Comment: Hi, I need java/kotlin code. Moreover, I need here-id, not the default country code.

Comment: Hi dear by using country code u can download the country Map accordingly

Answer (score 0):

**below is the code for country code**

```
    String UserIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserIP))
{
    UserIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
string url = "http://freegeoip.net/json/" + UserIP.ToString();
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string jsonstring = client.DownloadString(url);
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserCountryCode"] = dynObj.country_code;
```

> Using the above function you can get Country code so that you can directly pass it as a parameter to your function
>   ex: mMapLoader.installMapPackages(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserCountryCode"])
>
> In Java

```
    public static final Map<String, String> COUNTRY_MAP;
static {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("AF", "afghanistan"); // here put your country dynamically 
    map.put("AL", "albania");
    ...
    map.put("ZW", "zimbabwe");
    COUNTRY_MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap( map );
}
```